# If database has no record, return a declared int

Tags: c#, web-services, sql-server-2008, pushdown-automaton

I'm facing a problem. In my case, I would like to select max and + 1 in order to create a new receipt number, if it is a new receipt, it will create a new number as the code below shown. However, I'm getting the error

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other type

here is my code.

> this system is running on PDA, so I'm using this web service to call database

```
public string callReceipt(string terminal, ref string msg)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = "Select MAX(ReceiptNo) from ReceiptStore where terminalno ='" + terminal + "'";
            Logging.Log.writeLog(sql);
            msg = "Success";
            int receiptno = Convert.ToInt32(Data.DAL.ExecuteScalar(sql));
            if (!(sql is DBNull))
            {
                return Convert.ToString(receiptno + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                int receipt = 100000;
                return receipt.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            msg = "Error : " + e.Message.ToString();
            Logging.Log.writeLog(msg);
            return msg;
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
```

****** UPDATE ******

Thanks for all the answers, SimpleVar has provided the correct answer and it solved my problem. thanks again!

Comment: It would be better to use a stored-procedure instead of incrementing the value on client side. Otherwise it's a race condition(1-another app has access to `ReceiptStore` 2-this app is used by multiple users 3- database is accessed directly).

Comment: Mark SimpleVar´s anser as the correct one instead of updating your question or upvote the usefull ones.

Comment: @HimBromBeere i accepted, I was unable to accept before this due to SO ask me to wait for few minute. No worries, I will always accept the correct answer. Thanks for the reminding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
object o = Data.DAL.ExecuteScalar(sql);
if (o is int)
{
    return ((int)o + 1).ToString();
}
else
{
    int receipt = 100000;
    return receipt.ToString();
}
```

Besides that, you should look into stored procedures and prepared queries.

And for incrementing keys, you shouldn't use either, but use the appropriate database functionality that is auto-increment id columns.

Answer (score 1):

`sql` can never be `DBNull`as the first is a simple sting, not the result of the query. The error occurs because you want to convert `Data.DAL.ExecuteScalar(sql)` to an int which will not work if `ExecuteScalar` does not return anything (or in particular returns `DBNull`).

You have to check the result of that method against `DBNull`:

```
var o = Data.DAL.ExecuteScalar(sql);
int receiptno;

if (!(o is DBNull)) receiptno = Convert.ToInt32(o) + 1;
else receiptno = 100000;

return receiptno.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325(v=sql.120).aspx) operator.

```
Select MAX(ISNULL(ReceiptNo,0)) from ReceiptStore
```

Note: Please use parameters insted of string concatenation!

Comment: `Coalesce` (instead of `ISNULL`), could be a better solution, since it's a -*SQL 92* one (and thus compartible across RDBMS's)

Answer (score 0):

runn **SELECT @@ROWCOUNT** after your select query that will return you number of affected records in your previous query